# Why aren't tags with zero questions auto deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a few  zero questions tags like [russian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian),[russian-phonetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian-phonetic)

Why those are not deleted automatically?

Comment: We don't want to offend the Russians ....

Comment: Tags are deleted on a nightly job where they're not present on any questions. However, it looks like the russian tag for instance has been tidied up as the only two questions it did exist on where deleted 7 hours ago. So it'll be gone in the next run of the cleanup script.

Comment: *In soviet Russia you don't delete tags. Tags delete you.*

Comment: @JonClements better add a [tag:status-completed] to this

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The tags were still in use up until 7 hours ago on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487431/is-there-a-russian-keyboard-layout-which-is-also-suitable-for-programming) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdFR3.png)).

Since the tag clean-up script only runs once per day, at 03:00 UTC (or 04:00 UTC depending on who you ask), you'll have to wait until then for those tags be removed completely.

You can always do a quick inspection for tags in SEDE with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/708363?tag=russian) on the PostsWithDeleted table:

```sql
select id as [Post Link]
from postswithdeleted 
where tags like '%<' + ##tag:string?russian## + '>%'
```

Comment: Or you can use [the PostTags and Tags tables](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/708849/882284/). DE is only updated once a week, so you probably don't need to check WithDeleted for this (which I'm assuming includes deleted posts).

Comment: @Dukeling you are right but as it happened to be I was investigating something else around tags which made that I had this particular query already going. I used this more out of me being lazy instead of trying be as effective as possible.

Comment: I can't believe some one with that high of rep even asked that question *and some one else actually bothered to answer*...  I think it could have been migrated to another exchange site though.

Comment: @snb well, at least it wasn't in the category *halp plz, urgent, need script*, tagged with [tag:russian] ...

Comment: @rene I'd expect it to be tagged with [tag:emergency] in that case ;)